# mod_rewrite rewrite broken URL and bad query string

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with mod_rewrite. There's a broken external link to my site that looks something like this:

http://www.example.com/foo/page?myparam=AB/some-garbage.asp?bar=123

I'm trying to create a mod_rewrite rule to fix it (delete the last slash and everything after it). I've tried various things like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} myparam=AB/ [NC]
RewriteRule (myparam=AB.*) myparam=AB [L,R]
```

I have this rule at the top of the rule list, but I get a "Forbidden you don't have access to /foo/page on this server" error. If I delete the last "?" and everything after that from the URL, then the handler for this URL has a parameter of myparam with a value "AB/some-garbage.asp".

I've also tried REQUEST_URI and THE_REQUEST but nothing seems to rewrite this URL. Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(myparam=AB)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/foo/page)$ $1?%1 [L]
```

The parts inside parentheses `()` can be more general regular expressions, should you need to match a wider variety of query strings and URIs.

**EDIT**

The `RewriteRule` above assumes it's not being used in a `.htaccess` file, but rather in an apache server `.conf` file (such as `httpd.conf`).

If your rewrite rule is in an `.htaccess` file, you need to omit the leading directory part of the URI from the `RewriteRule`'s match pattern. For example, if your `.htaccess` file is in the `foo` directory on the server, then your `RewriteRule` should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(page)$ $1?%1 [L]
```

(Note how this command is the same as the one above, but with the `/foo/` prefix removed from the match pattern.)

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work. The rewrite condition doesn't seem to match the "/".

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: The only .htaccess is in the html root directory. so my rule is ^(foo/page)$, but $1 in the substitution is replaced by '/var/www/html/foo/page', so I physically made the substitution '/page/foo?%1' which works for now. And Thanks!

Comment: Found out that in order to have $1 not include '/var/www/html' I need the directive 'RewriteBase /' right after the 'RewriteEngine On' directive, and then I can use your answer. Very cool!

Comment: So my final solution is 'RewriteCond (myparam=\w+)/' and 'RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1' all with a 'RewriteBase /' after the 'RewriteEngine On'